# ShrePoint 2016 + workflow 2013 export\import

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016

After export site and imported in another scope workflow 2013 don't work and not associated with list

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of **Exporting / Importing site** does not preserve workflows, unfortunately, it's one of the disadvantages of the Exporting / Importing.

---

**The alternatives workaround**

1. Use [Backup-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Restore-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for site collection instead of `Import` and `Export` where this will ensure that everything is restored.
2. Or try to recreate the workflows manually by

   - Opening the SharePoint designer in both source and destination site
   - Create your list workflow, In source workflow `Select All` Steps and move it to the destination workflow.
3. Or try to use 3rd party migration tool like sharegate, metalogix
4. Or Use `Save Workflow as Template` as I mentioned at [Backup & restore Designer workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96482/backup-restore-designer-workflow/192274#192274)

Comment: It seems the steps in the reference link applies to only for 2010 workflow. Am I right?

Comment: It would work for SP 2013 too, Do you try it in SP 2013 and it's not working!? please confirm! I also remembered the **save as template** option for SP 2013 let me add it :)

Comment: I am checking "All Files" -> Workflows folder. There are only 2010 workflows. And for 2010 workflow "Save as Template" option is not working. So I am thinking for 2013 Save as Template is an option.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, I also checked it now it's working for SP 2010 workflow platform and the custom reusable workflow too. let me remove this link from the answer and add another option :)